# JMS Messages pending WebLogic 12

Tags: jms, weblogic12c

We are experiencing relatively random situation when the messages which are sent to the particular queues ending up as Messages Pending. The only way to solve the problem is to restart an associated Managed Server where an MDB is deployed. There are no Errors/Exceptions in the Managed Server log files. In the Admin Console of the WebLogic we can see that there are "stuck threads" in the Managed Server where we have MDB. What's even more strange is the fact that despite having a lot of messages pending an MDB continues to listen to the Queue and process the messages which arrive later.

Is there any way to resolve the issue without restarting Managed Server?

Comment: did you had any luck fixing this ? If so please add the answer. Myself and others will benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you is to go on server -> Monitoring -> Threads

You will see a list of threads currently running on your managed server.  Look for the threads marked as stuck or hogging and jot down their numbers..

Then, click on Thread Dump on top of the page and look for the stack with the number of your thread... You will see exactly which method is holding your thread and hogging your MDB.

Hope it helps !!!